# what would be the effect on searching if you we applied index on null field

Tags: mysql

what would be the effect of applying index on a column whose default value is null and it contains data?
e.g

```
create table mytable
(id int not null,
name varchar null);
```

what would be the effect on searching if you we applied index on 'name' field
any one can help

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Full Text search... here is the documentation...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

but using a third party full text search engine like elastic search, solr, lucene or sphinx is the most effective way to handle such as situations.

Answer (score 0):

The index on a column with null values will also index the columns with null values. The existence of null values will not change the performance behaviour.

Comment: agreed.In my case i have make a field default value 'null' and apply index on it.When i use explain extended it shows 3 in 'rows' column.it should show 1 in 'rows' column?

Comment: Did not understand. And I think, that's an other question.

Comment: i have a query explain extended SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
name = 'acdad'; as i applied index on name and by default its value is null.it is scanning 3 rows intead of 1.i am asking does default value null have impact on it??

Comment: Please post a new question or modify this question with your EXPLAIN-result and your exact question.